# How to set variable in high chart data field

Tags: javascript, java, spring, highcharts

Data is coming properly from backend and i am able to see the data using alert in java script. But unable to set the data dynamically in data part of high chart (bar chart).

```js
var cwk = "${myFormpage.cweek}";
var cwk2 = "${myFormpage.cweek2}";
var cwk3 = "${myFormpage.cweek3}";

var series = [{
    name: 'This week',
    color: '#ed7717',
    data: [11000, 12000, 17000]
  }, {
    name: '4 week ago',
    color: '#bd0066',
    data: [11000, 12000, 17000]
  }, {
    name: '52 week back',
    color: '#691e7d',
    data: [10000, 11000, 14000]
  }
];
```

The above code snippet is working fine.But, if i am adding the data dynamically like

```
data: [cwk,cwk2,cwk3]
```

chart is not getting created . Please help me how to add dynamic data here without ajax call.

Comment: `console.log()` the values of your `cwk`, `cwk2`, and `cwk3` variables, and post them here. You need to make sure that the values you expect are there, and that they are in the right format (numbers rather than strings, for example)

Comment: cwk is12345fwk is12345fwk1 is :12345

Comment: console.log("cwk is"+cwk+"fwk is"+ fwk+"fwk1 is :"+fwk1);

Comment: I don't understand your response. You are providing `[cwk,cwk2,cwk3]` as your data array. What are those values coming through as? When you `console.log(cwk)`, what is the value that is logged? And is it an integer? Or a string? Or something else?

Comment: You cwk* variables  defined as strings. Series expects numbers.

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'Java'?

Comment: it is tagged as java and in java part and in controller class it is like this:

Comment: int cweek= myFormpage.getCweek();                        model.addAttribute("cweek", cweek);

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in your code, it seems that you convert your values to strings in here:

```js
var cwk = "${myFormpage.cweek}";
var cwk2 = "${myFormpage.cweek2}";
var cwk3 = "${myFormpage.cweek3}";
```

Change to:

```js
var cwk = ${myFormpage.cweek};
var cwk2 = ${myFormpage.cweek2};
var cwk3 = ${myFormpage.cweek3};
```

And it should work...

Comment: `${variable}` is not valid ECMAScript.

Comment: This would be valid for binding though: `<div data-value="{variable}">`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I assumed that this should be substituted by a number with whatever templating engine is used by the app.